# Shortened Greeting?

Tags: manga, greetings, abbreviations, informal

I would like to know of what term "ちゃーす" is the abbreviated version. It appears to be a greeting. Translation software and my closest dictionary were of no help.

[image: Keiichi Arawi - CITY - 南雲さんのちゃーす]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simply こんにちは + a highly reduced です.

(EDIT: I claimed this isn't common in real life speech, but I'll defer to l'électeur's experience and remove that claim.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure ちゃーす is used outside fiction not too infrequently

Comment: Two people have already said that to me this morning just before noon.  One is a delivery driver and the other, a neighbor.  I expect a couple more to do the same in the afternoon as well.